# Recoding missing values into conditional means

Tags: statistics, spss, missing-data

Consider a dataset with 4 variables - ***RespondentID***, ***Site***, ***Year***, and ***Price***. I want to replace missing values in ***Price*** with a mean of ***Price*** for the exact ***Year*** and ***Site*** .

For example, if in ***Year*** 2009 in Paris mean reported ***Price*** was 22, i want to replace every missing ***Price*** value for which ***Year***=2009 and ***Site***=Paris with 22.

If i wanted to replace missing values with a zero (for example), i would create a syntax `RECODE Price (SYSMIS=0) (ELSE=COPY)`, but i have no idea how to implement this conditional mean thing.

I also know that one can find each conditional mean using `temporary. select if Year=2009 and Site=Paris. compute NewVar=mean(Price)`. However, there are too many combinations of ***Site*** and ***Year*** in my dataset to do it manually.
By the way, all the variables in the actual dataset are numeric (I don't know whether it is important or not).

Any idea how to do it in SPSS or maybe in some other statistics software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AGGREGATE /OUT=* MODE=ADD /BREAK=Site Year /Price_mean=MEAN(Price).
if missing(price) price=Price_mean.
execute.
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the AGGREGATE and MATCH commands (or RMV with SPLIT FILE).
EDIT:
Added example.

```
DATASET NAME rawdata.
SORT CASES BY Year Site.
DATASET DECLARE agg.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE agg / BREAK Year Site / Mean_Price=MEAN(Price).
MATCH FILES FILE =rawdata / TABLE agg / BY Year Site .
IF MISSING(Price) Price=Mean_Price.

*ALTERNATIVELY.
DATASET NAME rawdata.
SORT CASES BY Year Site.
SPLIT FILE BY Year SITE.
RMV /Mean_Price=SMEAN(Price).
IF MISSING(Price) Price=Mean_Price.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```